# Display data on spinner passed by previous activity

Tags: android

Here is my project description.

I have Activity A and Activity B , Activity B have a spinner and text field now i need to pass data from Activity A to Activity B and display it on spinner and text field. i have displayed data on text field but do not know how to display it on spinner.

Comment: This might help you. http://www.dcpagesapps.com/developer-resources/android/21-android-tutorial-spinners?showall=1

Comment: single data or list of of data means String array u have passed from activity A

Comment: @Khan passing single data from activity A to B

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve data using [Activity Extras](http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-using-intents-to-pass-data-and-return-results-between-activities/) and then do it like this:

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
        new String[] { "Apple", "Peach", "Banana" });
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```